# Selection of software architecture or lib to optimize UDP client on a point-to-point network

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

My goal is to drop as few UDP datagrams as possible.  Shocker, I know,  ;-)

Here is my circumstance which is a bit different from the general network server/client optimization questions for which I see a lot of discussion:

I am writing socket code for a process which has one singular goal:  grab UDP packets received by my Gigabit Ethernet NIC and get them into application RAM with as high a bandwidth as possible (i.e. minimize packet drops/loss).

The network is point-to-point without any firewalls, switches, routers, etc - just a single Cat6 cable connecting the UDP datagram generator/server (an embedded system) with my Windows 7 PC, the datagram receiver/client.  I can control the transmitted datagrams-per-second via some controls on the datagram generator.  The datagrams are sent to the broadcast address (FF.FF.FF.FF).

I've successfully achieved about 250-300Mbits/sec (30% of the theoretical 1G Ethernet bandwidth) without any packets getting dropped or order-scrambled by using lean-and-mean code based on the built-in Winsock2 commands:  select() and recvfrom() as outlined in the sample code for those commands on MSDN.

(I've already adjusted the receive buffer to be very large using the setsockopt() command, and this helped considerably.)  But I am still wanting to maximize performance and eager to hear thoughts from this community on whether or not I should expect noticeable gains from trying the following:

- Asynchronous I/O, such as boost::asio. From what I gather, this library appears to be more for optimizing applications which have to serve a lot of different sockets to different machines.  Should I expect much in terms of single-socket UDP receive performance from switching from Winsock to an asynchronous I/O architecture?
- Packet size:  If I make the effort to change the packet size by modifying the embedded code that is generating the packets, would it be likely to improve performance by having lots of smaller packets or fewer large/jumbo packets?
- Broadcast/multicast/unicast:  is one destination address type likely to perform better than others?
- Or is 300Mbps about the limit that I should be expecting for actual throughput on a 1G physical link?
- Any other recommendations on low-hanging fruit to improve performance, or expectations on what type of performance is feasible.

Thanks all!

Comment: Change architecture to IOCP?

Comment: You've probably already thought of this and just didn't mention in your post, but in case you haven't:  spawn a separate thread that does nothing but receive UDP packets and place them into an incoming-packets queue (preferably lockless), and run that thread at high priority.  Then another thread can pull packets off the other end of the queue without fear of packets getting dropped (although if it's too slow the queue might become very large and eat up all of your RAM...)

Comment: Thanks @MartinJames, I looked into IOCP further and much of the discussion touts its advantages compared to the traditional single-threaded approach, however, I get the impression that it is advantageous only for networks where there are lots of clients connecting to a server and efficient parallelism is required.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, yes, the code is already in a dedicated thread which does nothing but enqueue the data and then repeat.  The data pulled from that queue is used elsewhere in a lower priority thread.  It's getting them into this queue as fast as possible that I'm currently concerned with.   Thanks again!